# Motion tracking: model twitching in video

Tags: tracking

How to fix the twitching of the model added in motion tracked video and how to move it on the stage to change its position in the video

Blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10sY8y1_tvQBmz4a_zDxZ056aUMj6uTQR/view?usp=sharing

Video:

https://www.veed.io/view/60ba7ff0-91b6-4f68-87bb-56bca75cb569?panel=share

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.